# Case sensitive return Statement

Tags: python

I have a question about user input and the return statement.

For example, if I wanted a user to enter a color they would type, `Blue` or maybe `blue`.

I understand that python is case sensitive, so capitalized `Blue` and lowercase `blue` are not the same thing.

In the program I am making, the program randomly generates four different colors.

The problem is that when I assign the color value to a random number, the string text color is capitalized.

Would it be possible to maybe accept uppercase words as well as lowercase words with the return statement?

```
def randomNum():
    num = random.randint(1,7)
    return num

def randomColor():
    if randomNum() == 1:
        return "Blue"
    elif randomNum() == 2:
        return "Green"
    elif randomNum() == 3:
        return "Pink"
    elif randomNum() == 4:
        return "Purple"
    elif randomNum() == 5:
        return "Red"
    else:
        return "Yellow"
```

Comment: You can shorten this with `import random; return random.choice(['Blue', 'Green', 'Pink', 'Purple', 'Red', 'Yellow']).lower()`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that, at the point where you're calling the function, the comparison is made in a case-insensitive fashion. Try this, when comparing the strings:

```
randomColor().lower() == expected_color.lower()
```

Also, you can simply return the strings in lowercase:

```
return "blue" # same with the others
```

… And perform the comparison accordingly:

```
randomColor() == expected_color.lower()
```

Comment: Is there a way to only do this to the return statement in the definition?

Comment: @Nocturne what do you mean? The return statement just gives you a value back. You can't cause it to affect the value the user gave you. The fix is to change the user input to lowercase while doing the comparison.